# TextJustify-Android not loading and scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

Using the library [TextJustify-Android](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) there are two issues for me

1. **The text is not loaded/shown** when I open the `Activity` for the first time only when I open it for the next time. Providing image from emulator (same situation on phone)
   [image: text-not-loaded]
2. The text is shown, justified but **not scrollable**. Was changing the parameters, including `maxLines`, nothing helped. Providing the full `XML

---

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/blog"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="420dp"
            android:id="@+id/blogWrapper"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/blogInfo"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/blogImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/blog_title"
                android:id="@+id/blogTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/blogBlogger"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blogBlogger"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blogBlogger"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/blog_blogger"
                android:id="@+id/blogBlogger"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blogImage"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blogImage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/blogInfo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            >

        <com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView
            xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/blogText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            ext:documentView_cacheConfig="auto_quality"
            ext:documentView_antialias="true"
            ext:documentView_hyphen="-"
            ext:documentView_reverse="false"
            ext:documentView_textAlignment="justified"
            ext:documentView_textFormat="plain"
            ext:documentView_textSize="14sp"
            ext:documentView_textSubPixel="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blogButtonsSocial"
        android:layout_below="@+id/blogWrapper"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blogLike"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/global_button_dislike_image"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:text="FB"
                android:src="@drawable/global_button_social_facebook_image"
                android:id="@+id/blogLinkFacebook"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/global_button_social_facebook"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/global_button_social_twitter_image"
                android:id="@+id/blogLinkTwitter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/global_button_social_twitter"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blogDislike"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/global_button_like_image"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loginFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/global_footer_skyline"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/blogLinkTwitterPopup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:context=".BlogActivity"
        >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How you can vinculate with code ? DocumentView documentView = (DocumentView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.blogText); ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `maxLines` attribute from the XML layout. Currently you are setting the maxLines which seems to limit the content to just 100 lines. And don't put `DocumentView` inside a `ScrollView` because `DocumentView` is actually a subclass of `ScrollView`.

As a sidenote, I recommend you check out the `SqueezeHyphenator` which will hyphenate your text inside `DocumentView`

**UPDATE**: It works fine for me. You can see my [demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hernb795uxf1ds3/2015_01_27_03_55_43.mp4?dl=0). I can post my demo code on Github upon request.

Maybe you are not calling `documentView.requestLayout()` after you set the text.

Comment: Raised an issue here: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android/issues/60

Comment: @sitilge How do you set the text?